# XPATH - How to select <tag> after a particular <tag> element?

Tags: xpath

This is my document structure

```
<item_name>Item 1</item_name>
<item_description>Item 1 Description</item_description>

<item_name>Item 2</item_name>
<item_description>Item 2 Description</item_description>
...
... More <item_*> elements

<item_name>Item 400</item_name>
<item_description>Item 3 Description</item_description>

<item_name>Item 401</item_name>
<item_description>Item 4 Description</item_description>
...
... More <item_*> elements
```

I want to select the `text()` elements for description where `item_name is "Item 400" and "Item 401"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `following-sibling` axis**. For example, assuming that each and every `item_name` is followed by `item_description` element :

```
//item_name[.='Item 400' or .='Item 401']/following-sibling::item_description[1]/text()
```

or in case some `item_name` may have no corresponding `item_description` and you want to return nothing in that case :

```
//item_name[.='Item 400' or .='Item 401']
/following-sibling::*[1][self::item_description]
/text()
```

Comment: @wolfgang It is unfortunate to tell you that I don't have one. I just started at the very beginning with [XPath axes intro from w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp) due to it's simplicity, not because it is a good reference. Then I exercise and expand my knowledge & skills by answering new XPath questions and reading already answered questions here in SO. A little tips, when you learn new axis/syntax, make sure you master it well before moving forward to learn another, that way is less confusing, at least that's the way I did.

Comment: how is `//following-sibling` different from `/following-sibling`?

Comment: `//` is shortcut for `descendant-or-self::node()`. So, `//following-sibling` returns sibling nodes following current context node as well as those following every descendant of current context node